# How should I find the circumradius of a triangle without assumption of equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Acute triangle ABC has area 845. Let D be the foot of the perpendicular from A to BC, and let E
be the foot of the perpendicular from B to AC. The area of triangle CDE is 125, and the length of
DE is 20. The circumradius of triangle ABC can be expressed in the form a/b, where a and b
are relatively prime positive integers. Find a + b.

My work: line segment/ area relationships to get that $\dfrac{CD}{BC} \cdot \dfrac{EC}{AC} \cdot 845 = 125$. Then, $\dfrac{CD\cdot EC}{BC\cdot AC} = \dfrac{125}{845} = \dfrac{25}{169} = \left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)^2.$ So, I assumed that $\dfrac{CD}{ED} = \dfrac{BC}{AC} = \dfrac{5}{13}$ for a easier way out, giving a nice similarity. Also, with this, since the formula for a circumradius is $\dfrac{abc}{4A}$, I set both triangles ABC and CDE as equilateral to get $\dfrac{13^3}{4\cdot 845} = \dfrac{13}{20}$, so I got 13+20 = 33 as my answer.

My question: Do my assumptions lead to a possibly incorrect solution?

Comment: Aha! I forgot to use DE=20 to help with my similarity! But still, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Indeed $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DEC$, because

$$\frac{EC}{BC} = \frac{DC}{AC} = \cos \angle ACB$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider right-angled triangles $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle BEC$, which share a common angle $\angle C$ and right angles at $D$ and $E$. So these two triangles are similar, and

$$\frac{DC}{AC} = \frac{EC}{BC} = \cos \angle ACB$$

For $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEC$, their two corresponding sides are in ratio with included angle $\angle C$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\triangle ABC &\sim \triangle DEC\\
\frac{DE}{AB} &= \sqrt{\frac{\text{Area of }\triangle DEC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{125}{845}}\\
&= \frac{5}{13}\\
AB &= \frac{13}{5} DE = 52
\end{align*}$$

As $\cos \angle ACB = \frac{DC}{AC} = \frac{EC}{BC} = \frac{DE}{AB}$,

$$\begin{align*}
\cos\angle ACB &= \frac{5}{13}\\
\sin \angle ACB &= \frac{12}{13}\\
\end{align*}$$

The circumradius $R$ of $\triangle ABC$ can be obtained by the sine law,

$$\begin{align*}2R &= \frac{AB}{\sin\angle ACB}\\
&= \frac{52}{12/13}\\
&= \frac{169}{3}\\
R &= \frac{169}{6}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hi, how did you use the sine law with 2R?

Comment: @mathmule A theorem say: $\frac{AB}{sin \angle C}= \frac{AC}{sin \angle B}= \frac{CB}{sin \angle A}=2R$. See this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

Comment: @mathmule See the [relation of the law of sines and the circumcircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Relation_to_the_circumcircle), which also mentions your $R = \frac{abc}{4A}$ in your question.